# not able to get the file names depends upon the file creation time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

At present i am retrieving  the file names depends up on creation time of file ...

what i want is,i want to get all  the  files from 02/10/2011 to 02/11/2011(today date).(30 days difference)

(i.e) i want to get the file names from (`today day - 30 days`)

and  i want to get the file names from (`today day -90 days`)

for that i have done like this....

```
private void filteringFiles()
{
  string filenamepath = @"C:\defualt\Access\backupdb\";
  List<String> listfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\defualt\Access\backupdb\", "backup-*.zip").ToList();
  List<String> files = new List<String>();
  List<String> getfiles = new List<String>();
  foreach (var allfiles in listfiles)
  {

    files.Add(Path.GetFileName(allfiles));
    //DateTime creationtime = File.GetCreationTime(files);
  }
  if (cbbackupforms.Text == "Month")
  {
    getfiles = (from string s in files where (DateTime.Now.Day - Convert.ToInt32(File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).AddDays(-30)) < 1) && (DateTime.Now.Year - File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).Year == 0) select s).ToList();

  }
  if (cbbackupforms.Text == "3 Months")
  {

    getfiles = (from string s in files where (DateTime.Now.Day - Convert.ToInt32(File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).AddDays(-90)) < 3) && (DateTime.Now.Year - File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).Year == 0) select s).ToList();

  }    

  if (cbbackupforms.Text =="6 Months")
  {
    getfiles = (from string s in files where (DateTime.Now.Day - Convert.ToInt32(File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).AddDays(-180)) < 6) && (DateTime.Now.Year - File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).Year == 0) select s).ToList();

  }
  if (cbbackupforms.Text == "year")
  {
    getfiles = (from string s in files where ((DateTime.Now.Month - File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).Month) < 12) select s).ToList();

  } 


  listbackups.DataSource = getfiles;

}
```

but the i got the error  at this line

```
(DateTime.Now.Year - File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).Year == 0) select s)
```

like this...

```
ERROR:{"Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'."}
```

would any one pls help on this...
many Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE:** I am still getting the same error like this...

```
ERROR:{"Invalid cast from 'DateTime' to 'Int32'."}
```

at this line

getfiles = (from string s in files **where (DateTime.Now.Day - Convert.ToInt32(File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).AddDays(-30)) < 1) && ((DateTime.Now.Year - (File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s))).Year) == 0) select s).ToList();**

Comment: At first glance, everything looks OK, but is there a reason why you're not using DateDiff, and possibly streamlining the multiple List<string>'s to a single List<string>?

Comment: i dont know how to use that datediff in this case ....would you pls give any sample snippet for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line to

```
((DateTime.Now.Year - (File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s))).Year) == 0) select s)
```

UPDATE:

```
getfiles = (from string s in files where (DateTime.Now.Day - Convert.ToInt32(File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s)).AddDays(-30).Day) < 1) && ((DateTime.Now.Year - (File.GetCreationTime(Path.Combine(filenamepath, s))).Year) == 0) select s).ToList();
```

Comment: would you pls see my update still, i am getting same error that i have indicated in bold line

Comment: its was not giving any error but it was showing files that was created in September also but I don't want to show the files that was created in September ..would you pls help on this....

Comment: you are piling up a question after a question... please define first what you really want to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

Sample code: I was thinking VB stuff. But, this should do what you need?

```
        string filenamepath = @"C:\";   
        List<String> files = new List<String>();

        //change this TimeSpan based on your variable? 
        var timespan = new TimeSpan(30, 0,0,0,0);
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(filenamepath);
        files = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => f.CreationTime.Add(timespan) > DateTime.Now).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```